# Audioplayers package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class PlaybackScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String recordingPath;

  PlaybackScreen({required this.recordingPath});

  @override
  _PlaybackScreenState createState() => _PlaybackScreenState();
}

class _PlaybackScreenState extends State<PlaybackScreen> {
  late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  bool isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((PlayerState state) {
    if (state == PlayerState.COMPLETED || state == PlayerState.STOPPED) {
      setState(() {
         isPlaying = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Getting 2 error messages:
There's no constant named 'COMPLETED' in 'PlayerState'.
There's no constant named 'STOPPED' in 'PlayerState'.

Answer (score 0):

PlayerState from [audioplayers: ^5.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) is an [enum](https://dart.dev/language/enums). It's values are in lowercase.

```dart
 if (state == PlayerState.completed || state == PlayerState.stopped)
```